# Check if device is locked in Portrait mode

Tags: android, preference, setting

Is there way to get information if device settings is enable to locked screen orientation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check the value of [Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/Settings.System.html#ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION) setting like so:

```
final int rotationState = android.provider.Settings.System.getInt(
    getContentResolver(), 
    Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 0
);
```

When the auto-rotation is enabled, this value equals to 1 (and 0 otherwise).